# Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'date' before initialization

Tags: javascript

I'm getting this error "Cannot access 'date' before initialization"

```
document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', function () {
    let date = new date(date.now() + 86400000);
    date = date.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = 'acceptsCookies=true; path=/; expires=' + date;
});
```

Comment: JS is case-sensitive, use `Date` inside the value definition of `date`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be `Date` not `date`

```
let date = new Date(Date.now() + 86400000);
```

The interpreter thinks, that you use the `date` variable.

Comment: try `Date.now`?

Comment: Yes, it should be `Date.now()` I missed it, anyway he got the idea about that.

Comment: typos should not be answered

Comment: It's not about the typo only, it is about understanding the error, read the answer well.